# Underscore pass object as parameter

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm using Underscore.js to create a template. I want to make each button in the template pass in the response associated with it. I could do this using the response id, with:

```
<% _.each(responses, function(response){ %>
    <button class="btn btn-sm" onclick="citeResponse('<%= response._id %>')">Cite Response</button>
<% }); %>
```

and then use

```
$.grep(responses, function(e){ return e._id == id; });
```

To find the response based on the id. However, this makes me iterate over an array when I actually know exactly what response I want. I tried doing:

```
<% _.each(responses, function(response){ %>
    <button class="btn btn-sm" onclick="citeResponse('<%= response %>')">Cite Response</button>
<% }); %>
```

However, `citeResponse`always gets `[Object object]`. How can I return the actual object?

Comment: Can't you just set the id in your function and use that? I'd be wary of using the word "template" here since you're not using underscore templating at all.

Comment: Using an `onclick` attribute is sort of old school. Normally you'd attach an event handler and hook up the appropriate `response` object that way or maybe set a `data-response-id` attribute and have an id->object map somewhere visible to your event handlers.

Comment: @muistooshort What's an example of such an event handler?

Comment: Depends on what framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to pass through the argument is a JSON Object, you can just use `JSON.stringify(response)` to serialize it to string. Then, in your `citeResponse` function parse it to convert it back to an object with `JSON.parse(argument)`.

```
<% _.each(responses, function(response){ %>
<button class="btn btn-sm" onclick="citeResponse('<%= JSON.stringify(response) %>')">Cite Response</button>
```

```
function citeResponse(response) {
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    ...
}
```